# Run simultaneous process inside python class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm developping a game using pygame and I want to create a loading screen while the assets are loaded. The loading screen have animations, so loading screen and assets loading should be occurring at the same time.

Consider the code below:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
       self.loading_screen()
       self.load_assets()
    def loading_screen(self):
       # do something while load_assets() is running
    def load_assets(self):
       # load all assets needed
```

I've tried Process from multiprocessing, but I dont know how to keep loading_screen() running without freezes while load_assets() are running.

Also, I've tried threads, but python doesn't run threads simultaneously, so, in some moment, the loading_screen() will freeze. (This could be wrong, but this was observed in the game)

Some help about this?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Threads are suitable for this. Nothing runs exactly simultaneously on a multi user system anyway.

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loading_screen()
    def loading_screen(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.load_assets)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        while t.isAlive():
            sleep(0.1)
            print("loading screen")
        print ("assets done, ready to proceed now")

    def load_assets(self):
        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            print("loading assets")
            i += 1
            sleep(1)

g = Game()
print("done")
```

This puts your asset loading to a thread and then enters `loading_screen()` in the main thread. This just prints messages to demonstrate they both run in parallel.

Comment: Nice! But how this should be implemented if the loading_screen() should run completely while load_assets() doesn't finish? With loading_screen() rendering animations, is possible that it freezes because cpu interrupt loading_screen() processing to process load_assets().

Comment: I have modified the answer. In this case, you would launch the thread from `loading_screen()` and then `join()` the thread.  This will block until the thread has finished. If `load_assets()` takes less time than load screen, then there is no difference. If load_assets takes longer, your loading_screen blocks until all assets have been loaded.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2pgzBx see this code. The while loop inside loading_screen() cannot be interrupted because can produce freezes in animation. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need this loop?  If you want to ensure t.join() does not block, then remove t.join() and in your while loop use `while t.isAlive():`  This will keep your while loop running as long as your  load_assets thread is running and it exits only when your thread has finished. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: see my latest edit.  I do not know if I can help you much more with this, as you seem to have requirements I do not quite understand.  This code starts asset loading and stays in the while loop until done, no matter how long it takes. Only when the thread exits, the while loop exits as well.

Comment: hahaha Sorry. Maybe I'm not being very clear. However, your answers already help me a lot and I can adapt my solution using this answers. But, to clarify, see this code https://codeshare.io/GAEQA8 (are you using linux?). Notice that load_assets() interrupts the animation when it is still running. In pygame, this will stop the animation for a moment, what is not desired.

Comment: I dont know how much time the animation will be stucked by the thread change, so I can't create a personalized animation for this transition.

Comment: What is happening: animation start > back to load_assets() > animation finish > back to load_assets() > animation start

Comment: What is desired: animation start > animation finish > back to load_assets() > animation start > animation finish > back to load_assets()

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what problems the OP is having, a preferred solution is to use **multiprocessing** rather than *multithreading*. The given demo from the first answer uses time.sleep for simulating 'heavy loading' in the loading function, but when loading is actually going to take place, it will take a major amount of performance out of the CPU.
So it might happen that your loading animation is playing at 5-10 FPS when you expected 100+ FPS from it.

In this case, it is best to use multiprocessing to achieve the same. From what I have heard, it is a bit complicated to implement it, but it is quite possible. The loading function will then run as a separate process, not a separate thread from the same process.

Here is a small demo program to illustrate a loading screen using multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection


def loading_screen(conn: Connection, stage):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60
    c = 0
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('consolas', 25)
    while True:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 50))
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return
        if conn.poll():  # check if any object is available to be received or not
            # this line is used to prevent waiting until the next object is received
            c = conn.recv()  # if available, receive the object
        if c == 'end':
            # process end condition checking
            return
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', (50, 50, c, 50))
        screen.blit(font.render(f'{c} / {stage * 100} %     [stage {stage}]', True, 'white'), (50, 150))
        screen.blit(font.render('Check console for status', True, 'white'), (50, 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
        pygame.display.set_caption(f'Multiprocessing Loading Screen [FPS = {int(clock.get_fps())}]')


def resource_load(conn: Connection, items):
    # load resources
    # for now it increments a counter and sends it via the connection object
    # you can replace it for CPU intensive processes
    # and pass the loaded objects to the connection object
    c = 0
    while True:
        c += 1
        if c > items:
            conn.send('end')  # signal end of loading current stage
            return  # returning will end the process automatically
        conn.send(c)  # send the counter value via the connection object


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pygame

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))  # initialize display

    receiver, sender = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)  # initialize sender and receiver connection objects [unidirectional]

    print('Program to demonstrate a simple loading screen using multiprocessing')
    print()

    print('starting stages...')
    multiprocessing.Process(target=resource_load, args=(sender, 100)).start()
    print('loading stage 1')
    loading_screen(receiver, 1)
    multiprocessing.Process(target=resource_load, args=(sender, 200)).start()
    print('loading stage 2')
    loading_screen(receiver, 2)
    multiprocessing.Process(target=resource_load, args=(sender, 300)).start()
    print('loading stage 3')
    loading_screen(receiver, 3)
    input('finished loading all stages... press Enter to exit console')  # press Enter inside the console to exit program
```

EDIT:
I have made a video on this if interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWGDgPldPVo